# TYPO3: Schedule SQL statement

Tags: typo3, scheduler

Is there and easy way to schedule a SQL call in TYPO3?

A core function or extension to schedule a custom SQL call?

It is for old TYPO3 4.5.29.
If someone now same thing for TYPO3 6.1/6.2 then I would like to read about that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Scheduler, that is supposed to be executed via cronjob. You can add your own tasks to the Scheduler from an extension and define how often it should be executed. The Scheduler comes with the core. You maybe have to install it.

Further Information about how to do it:

- http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/latest/DevelopersGuide/CreatingTasks/Index.html
- http://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/extensions/scheduler.html
- http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/latest/Index.html